# Как правильно идентифицировать пользователя в unity?

Tags: android, unity3d, ios, auth, аутентификация

Хочу создать игру в `unity` чтобы и на `google play` и в `appstore` опубликовать, сервер на `php+mysql`.

Как в `unity` правильно авторизовать и идентифицировать пользователя для обоих платформ.

В некоторых играх увидел, что используют `Google Play Game` на android.
На `ios Game Center`.

Но заметил, что даже когда я поменял аккаунт на google play games и авторизовался с новым аккаунтом, то все данные от прошлого аккаунта сохраняются.

Решил попробовать, использовал `Play Game Plugin v11.01` и `Play Games Services v2`.
В последней версии `email` и возможность программного выхода убрали.
Есть `auth_token` который меняется каждый раз, и есть `user_id` который не меняется.

Укажите пожалуйста, как в unity правильно реализовать эти моменты?